# Advice needed on running UF wire to lantern pole

Tags: electrical, outdoor

I am electrifying a pole gas lantern and want to run outdoor wire to the pole. 
I would appreciate some advice on how to accomplish this project.
The interior side of a brick wall close to the pole has an electrical receptacle outlet that I want to use to tap the UF wire into.
I intend to replace the old receptacle with a GFCI  and tap into it connecting the run of UF cable to an LB PVC box on the exterior brick wall and bury the cable 12” deep to the lantern pole which is 12’ away.

What would be the most efficient place to start the wire run? 
Should I start from the top of the pole and pull the wire from there to the LB box on the brick wall or the other way around?
Any advice in accomplishing this project would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running conduit and talking about pulling the wire?

Comment: Why 12"? That's normally too shallow...

Comment: If the existing fixture and gas pipe are in good shape buy a 24v gas light conversion kit.  It consists of 2x12v lampholders prewired in series, 24v photocell, wire you can pull in the existing gas pipe, and typically a plug in transformer.  (There are also now LED versions of the same kit--I've never personally seen LED versions)--the non LED versions typically use 2 1156 bayonet base automotive lamps--due to voltage drop on the 24v line they dim slightly naturally and 1)look great 2) rarely burn out.

Comment: The NF cable will be run thru grey conduit and I learned it must be at least buried 18 inches